# Where temporary store data C#, WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, temporary

I am writing an app, which it will have form for configuration.

Under configuration I have different buttons what to do with configuration:

Load - load configuration from file (csv, xml,...) and update app form to configuration; Save - save configuration from actual app form to file (csv, xml,...) Set configuration - save until config form for configuration App default configuration - when app open, default configuration will be set up

So because I have 5 different configuration but in the same format, where is god to save it or where to load temporary data?

**Is better to use Singleton Pattern or write to some file?**

Entire app is written in C#, WPF, MVVM. I want just to save context of checkboxes (true,false) and textbox context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities:

User specific data, in a file: [Application.UserAppDataPath Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.userappdatapath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

User specific data in Registry: [Application.UserAppDataRegistry Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.userappdataregistry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Furthermore there are all standard paths in the environment: [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), see `CommonApplicationData` and `ApplicationData`

Comment: `Application.UserAppDataPath` is also user specific!

Comment: Yes, I modifoed my answer